# Redirect website on correct URL

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

I want to redirect my site to custom URL for example if I am using abcwww.test.com then it's working but i want to redirect this on www.test.com. before www if I am using anyhting like xyz, try anything it's working I want to remove these things from my URL and redirect to simple www.test.com.

I don't want any update in code I want it by IIS if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can always split the string and take out any part and work on it. Strings allow you to do this.

Try this

```
string Url = Request.Url.ToString();
Url = "www." + Url.Split('.')[1] + Url.Split('.')[2];
```

It will take out the second and the last value, but will just make sure that the first value is always `www`.

#### IIS Url redirects

You can use codes to redirect the user from one page to another. But the same would be done. You will write the code, and will extract the part of the URL that must be same, and then use

```
Reponse.Redirect(Url);
```

..this will forward the user to the next page.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks @AfZaal I don't want to write any code I want to do this by IIS

Comment: @YogeshSharma, even IIS would require you to write some code. You can't expect IIS to do anything for you. :)

Comment: Yes,but IIS can do redirects with help HTTP Redirects and URL rewrites!